# Information needed to share with Penetration Tester?

Tags: penetration-test

We are planning for a penetration testing for our network and applications.

Can anyone confirm the details which should be shared to penetration testers regarding our topology / servers?

Is it required to provide them remote access to any of our app servers?

Comment: This is the same question you asked earlier, at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/113222/what-data-would-require-for-a-pen-tester - please provide the details requested there if you want a useful answer. I've recommended this question be closed due to this.